# Cannot create property 'selected' on string 'Information Technology' angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

> This is my controller

```
 $scope.subjects = ["Computer Security", "Graphics and Multimedia", "Networks", "Computer Science and Engineering", "Game Design", "Programming", "Information Technology", "Software Engineering", "Technology Management", "Telecommunications", "Web Development", "Sociology", "Psychology", "General", "Social Work", "Criminal Justice", "Law and Paralegal", "Public Safety", "Forensic Sciences", "Counseling", "Homeland Security", "Political Science", "Public Administration"];
```

> This is my view where i am binding data

```
 <label class="concentration-label3" ng-repeat="value in subjects">
        <input ng-model="value.selected" ng-disabled="subjectCheckedCount == subjectLimit && !value.selected" type="checkbox" name="concentrations" class="concentration-label3__input js-concentration-value" value="{{value}}" data-mixpanel-subject="Design" >
        <span class="concentration-label3__title" for="conc1">
            {{value}}
            <span class="concentration-label3__title__checkmark4"></span>
        </span>
 </label>
```

> Its giving me the error that 'cannot bind property selected to string
>   xyz' Please help!!!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/cdwY1EzKRAL0qlwC9eyO?p=preview .Its working for me ,its look like different reason

Comment: Its binding the data for me too, but in my $scope.$watch function when i try to get the property value.selected, then it shows me 'cannot create property on string' error in console..

Comment: Please add  watch scripta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subjects` is an array of strings, which don't have the property `selected` that you're trying to bind to your input.

Comment: So what should i do with subject to make it have property selected?

Comment: You could either just add a property to `$scope` like `selectedValue` or you could turn `subjects` into objects, i.e. `subjects = [{ value: "Computer Science", selected: false }, ...`

Comment: Thanks did the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var j = 0; j < $scope.subjects.length; j++){
    $scope.subjectsArray.push({
        'name':  $scope.subjects[j],
        'value': $scope.subjects[j]
    });   
}
```

> We must provide ng-repeat an object in order to create any property of
>   that object later. We cannot create a property of a string. So I converted my array of string into array of objects.