# Cannot create property 'selected' on string, using ngModel with Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngmodel

so I'm trying to use `[(ngModel)]` like this:

```
  <div class="items">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let account of this.accounts">
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="this.account.name.selected" name="account">
              {{account.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
```

My `accounts` is created and filled in the component: `accounts: Account[] = [];`

My `Account` object:

```
export class Account {
name: string;
surname: string;
}
```

I'm getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'selected' on string 'John'`

I saw this thread: [Cannot create property 'selected' on string 'Information Technology' angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437597/cannot-create-property-selected-on-string-information-technology-angularjs) But didn't quite understand how to apply mentioned fix to my case, maybe because I'm using Angular and not AngularJS. Would be glad if anyone could help a bit understanding the problem here?

Comment: Here name is `string`. It does not contains property `selected`. If it was an object then you could define a property `selected`.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that from the other thread, but how to I make it work?

Comment: Oh, I just removed the `.name` from `ngModel` and now it's object, got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: The checkbox will assign a boolean value to whatever it's bound to. So now you will have a boolean property on your `Account` instance. The checkbox will initially be unchecked since `selected` is initially undefined.

Comment: You need to change the type from string to object and declare desired properties for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to have `selected` property in your array. So to avoid polluting `Account` class, you can use `map` method:

```
let withSelectedProperty = this.accounts.map(s=> ({...s, selected: false}));
```

And HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let account of withSelectedProperty">
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="account.selected" name="account">
          {{account.name}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use method `filter` to get all selected values:

```
let onlySelected = this.withSelectedProperty.filter(f => f.selected);
```

Comment: And what if I just use it as an object like `[(ngModel)]="this.account.selected"`? It seems to be working. But how do I access the selected values? For example if I want to `console.log()` the selected elements in the component?

Comment: Ok, got it, but shouldn't there be `[(ngModel)]="this.account.selected"`? The `name` field is obsolete, no?

Comment: @developer1 ooops, I was in hurry, please, see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, and now why did you remove `this`?

Comment: @developer1 because `this` [is not necessary in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152290/using-this-keyword-in-angular-components-template)